# How can I see the `qsub` command used to submit a job?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

I have a job running in a remote cluster. Is there a way to see what `qsub` command was used (the options and so on) to start the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a 'qstat -f [job number]' and look for 'submit_args'.